# Google maps not displaying in ASP.MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I need some help with implementing a Google map into an application. I have tested this by using Localhost and the map is returned instantly. The issue I am having is when I have deployed it to an azure platform the maps are taking an age to return. Sometimes you have to refresh the page several times for the page to load.

I have generated an Google web API key and double checked this numerous times. I have also followed the Google tutorials on building the map with Javascript.

Here is what I have in the view.

```
    @model Phase5.Models.Supplier

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}


<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Supplier</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupplierName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SupplierName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddressLine2)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddressLine2)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Postcode)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Postcode)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Phone)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactName)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCR40cXGAT-hM1MqQkJQZ7NLqZOlJMXg20&callback=initMap"
            async defer type="text/javascript"></script>




    <!-- This css is to ensure that the google map contols (zoom bar etc) show and size correctly. -->
    <style>
        #map_canvas img {
            max-width: none;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- This css is to give a nice big popup "info window" when a marker is clicked on the map -->
    <style>
        .infoDiv {
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- This is the div that will contain the Google Map -->
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>

    <!-- Enclose the Javascript in a "section" so that it is rendered in the correct order after scripts have been loaded etc -->
    @section scripts {
        <section class="scripts">

            <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            Initialize();
        });
     function codeAddress(address) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 17,
                        center: results[0].geometry.location,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

                    }
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location

                    });
                    // create a marker
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map ,
                        title: 'Latitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.Ya + ' Longitude :' + results[0].geometry.location.Za
                    });
                }
            });

        }

        //Call this function with giving the address.
        codeAddress("@Model.Address + @Model.AddressLine2 + @Model.Postcode");

            </script>
        </section>
    }



    <br />

    <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.SupplierId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Do I need an web.config settings to be enabled for this to work fully or am I missing something

Many Thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove `async defer` from the script?

Comment: Your the man!!! works like a treat now.

Comment: I know it xD...i'm glad to help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Hackerman the answer is to remove the `async defer` from the script